# Can't update state on unmounted component/ useEffect returns null in the end

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

using context and firebase I try to use onAuthStateChange to set my user in the app. After receiving user useEffect runs again and returns null.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
// the context
const AuthUserContext = createContext();
// the higher order (wrapper)
const PureAuthState = ({ children, firebase }) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    authUser: null,
  });
  const { auth } = firebase;
  const onChange = authUser => {
    console.log(authUser);
    setAuthState({ authUser });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(onChange);
    // avoid memory leaks??
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={{ authState, setAuthState }}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const AuthState = withFirebase(PureAuthState);

export default AuthUserContext;
```

These are the lines I get from console.log in my browser

```
//// the user
context.js:12 P {G: Array(0), l: "AIzaSyBOAb8pWO...}

//// null
context.js:12 null
```

I don't understand why I get this null afterwards. After away for 2 days when it worked fine, this happened. Help!

Edit 1:
This is my SignIn component. I think this is the root of this problem.

```
const SignInFormBase = props => {
  const [form, setVal] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error: null,
  });
  const { firebase, history } = props;
  const { email, password, error } = form;
  const signIn = async () => {
    await firebase.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    setVal({ ...form });
    history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
  };
  const onSubmit = e => {
    try {
      signIn();
      // history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
    } catch (err) {
      setVal({ ...form, error: err });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

If I history.push outside the signIn function I get this warning and also still getting authUser as null afterwards.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Comment: it is impossible that useEffect runs twice for the same component load. Could it be you are unloading the component and unsubscribe is called and that trigger a call to onChange with null?

Comment: After I signing in a user with firebase in my SignIn component I , navigate them with history.push. I will update this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's going on with your code setup, but if you're trying to get the authenticated user you can do that in the constructor and then dispatch an appropriate action.

For example (ngrx 7 syntax):

```
  constructor(
    ...
  ) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      // No authenticated user, logout
      if (!user) {
        return this.store.dispatch(new ActionAuthLogout());
      } 
      // User is authenticated, load user document
      else if (user) {
        return this.store.dispatch(new ActionLoadUser());
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `{ authState, setAuthState }` you are passing a new reference on every-render

```
const PureAuthState = ({ children, firebase }) => {
  //.. rest removed for brevity.
  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={{ authState, setAuthState }}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Would you memoize the value before passing it to the context and try again?

```
const PureAuthState = ({ children, firebase }) => {
  //.. rest removed for brevity.
  const contextValue = React.memo(() => ({ authState, setAuthState }), [
    authState,
    setAuthState
  ]);

  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried the React.memo as follows and I get an error where authUser is undefined in my Navigation component. My Navigation component is just a navbar that uses the AuthUserContext. 
*Note: I have never tried React memo